# Nginx - Rewrite timestamped assets

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm currently in the process of moving from Apache to Nginx and am having problems with one of the rewrite rules. I have the following rule in my old .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]
```

How would I rewrite this rule for Nginx? Everything I try either doesn't work or simply prevents Nginx from reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
Location ~ \.(css|js)$ {
   rewrite "^(.+)\.\d{10}\.(css|js)$" $1.$2;
}
```

Comment: Had to wait 10 minutes ;)

Comment: Wow your a nginx expert too, I didnt know that before +1, Anubhawa ,Do you know about a webhosting site that provide free hosting with nginx server? I have problems with loading nginx server on my PC, and my C card isnt workin anymore. please.

Comment: @Starkeen: Sorry I don't know about hosting sites but will try to find out from my friends and will let you know.